# Using some packages adds a vertical offset when using LaTeX to render text in matplotlib/python figures

Tags: color, siunitx, matplotlib

I was advised to post here in the comments on a [post I made on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645097/why-does-the-siunitx-latex-package-add-a-vertical-offset-to-some-text-elements-i).

I'm using LaTeX to render my text in figures in the Python package matplotlib. My problem was that when I added siunitx to my LaTeX preamble, some elements of text were displaced vertically. I've solved that issue for myself by reverting to a previous version of siunitx, but I don't know the cause of the initial problem. It also occurs when using the package color.

The same problem wasn't reproduced by everybody:  I'm using python 3.8.12, matplotlib 3.3.2 and siunitx 3.0.32 (installed via MiKTeX) on Windows 10.

I was asked to upload the files in the .matplotlib\tex.cache folder here, in case it helps to debug the problem, which I have done below.

Thanks for your help!

**Incorrect alignment by using siunitx**

*Python script*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Test data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 64)
y = np.sin(x)

# Use latex for text
plt.rcdefaults()
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\n'.join([
    r'\usepackage{siunitx}',
])

# Generate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='some string')
ax.legend()
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[]) # Reduces number of text items in MWE
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('siunitx_v3.png')
plt.show()
```

*Image produced*
[image: Incorrectly aligned text with siunitx]

*.matplotlib\tex.cache files*

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mathdefault}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
\usepackage[papersize=72in,body=70in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% The empty hbox ensures that a page is printed even for empty inputs, except
% when using psfrag which gets confused by it.
\fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}%
\ifdefined\psfrag\else\hbox{}\fi%
{\sffamily lp}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mathdefault}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
\usepackage[papersize=72in,body=70in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% The empty hbox ensures that a page is printed even for empty inputs, except
% when using psfrag which gets confused by it.
\fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}%
\ifdefined\psfrag\else\hbox{}\fi%
{\sffamily some string}
\end{document}
```

(+ 2 dvi files)

**Correct alignment by forcing version 2**

*Python script*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Test data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 64)
y = np.sin(x)

# Use latex for text
plt.rcdefaults()
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\n'.join([
    r'\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]',
])

# Generate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='some string')
ax.legend()
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[]) # Reduces number of text items in MWE
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('siunitx_v2.png')
plt.show()
```

*Image produced*

[image: Correctly aligned text with siunitx version 2]

*.matplotlib\tex.cache files*

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mathdefault}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
\usepackage[papersize=72in,body=70in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]
\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% The empty hbox ensures that a page is printed even for empty inputs, except
% when using psfrag which gets confused by it.
\fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}%
\ifdefined\psfrag\else\hbox{}\fi%
{\sffamily lp}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mathdefault}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
\usepackage[papersize=72in,body=70in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]
\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% The empty hbox ensures that a page is printed even for empty inputs, except
% when using psfrag which gets confused by it.
\fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}%
\ifdefined\psfrag\else\hbox{}\fi%
{\sffamily some string}
\end{document}
```

(+ 2 dvi files)

**Edit**

Posting pngs created from both working and non working dvi files. Both look the same. (Images are larger than the text, but are white against the white Stack Exchange background).

*Working (siunitx version 2)*

[image: Working (siunitx version 2)]

*Not working (siunitx version 3)*

[image: Not working (siunitx version 3)]

Comment: could you compile one of the broken files with latex and then call dvipng ? How does the png look? Is it different to the png of the other version?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hello again, thanks for your help! In both cases they look the same: a rectangle with bottom-right aligned text. I'll add the images to the bottom of the question so you can see them.

Comment: @TomVincentUK, I have tried in chat and I have (I think) the same as you. Puzzling. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59406419#59406419

Comment: do you have any idea how matplotlib postprocessed the latex files? It doesn't seem to be a simply dvipng call as you have no problems with it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm afraid I don't know, sorry. I'll have a bit of a dig through the matplotlib source, but I can't promise I'll find anything.